# Why am I getting The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler. for .net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have been trying for days to serve my .net core 6 razor pages application in IIS.

I have published my app and pointed to IIS.

I gave the permissions and set the default pool and changed it to no manage code.

I am getting

The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

here is how am I browsing the page

http://10.39.2.131/Alrashedv2/Pages/Index.cshtml

in my startup class I have

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSession(); // After AddMvc()
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        }
```

Any reason ?

Comment: You are requesting a file with an extension. Razor Pages routes do not include extensions. You should read up about routing in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment: I tried /index not working

Comment: You should read the information I provided. Remove `/Pages` from the URL.